# How to get MYSQL JSON object value when don't know the key?

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have a column in MYSQL table from which I want to get object's first value, and I don't know what is the kay name. Values are like:

```
{"5":"ABC"} 
{"8":"CDE"}
```

I have tried JSON_EXTRACT, JSON_KEYS but nothing work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below query worked for me:

```
SELECT json_extract(json_data,'$[0].*') from table
```

For detailed documentation, go through [JSON_EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) once.

Comment: Thanks @Ankit, Following query is working for me. `SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(sender_id, '$[0].*'), '$[0]')) FROM table`

Comment: Great!! @Anandagrawal